# how to check how many users are currently logged in sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: central-administration

how to check how many users are currently logged in Sharepoint foundation 2010

Answer (score 3):

This is a complicated question.  HTTP is stateless, so it's difficult to know how many people are using the platform at a precise moment.

A really complete article is standing at the following URL : Check it out
[Here](http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if the above solution would work for Anonymous web site? may be at IIS level you can find find the user count.

Try this.
http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-current-users/sessions.html