# Get count  all users login in sharepoint

Tags: 2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check how many users are currently logged in sharepoint foundation 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6830/how-to-check-how-many-users-are-currently-logged-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010)

How 2 get all users which is loging in sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

This question has previously been looked at and answered:

[how to check how many users are currently logged in sharepoint foundation 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6830/how-to-check-how-many-users-are-currently-logged-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010)

Comment: Thanks Jim - please flag questions for the mods if you see a duplicate.