# list of current logged users on a given sp web application

Tags: web-analytics, user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check how many users are currently logged in sharepoint foundation 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6830/how-to-check-how-many-users-are-currently-logged-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010)

Is there a way to know who all are logged into the portal.abcd.com site? Is there a powershell or web analytic or Central admin process I can run to who all the logged into the portal site? or any SP site under sp web application.

Comment: See Sébastien Levert's
comment, he links to this article, http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site